# Rails 5 server switches to default port instead of specified port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I'm just setting up a new Mac (macOS 10.12.3).  I've installed RVM, Homebrew, etc.  The only Ruby installed so far is 2.4.0 and Rails is 5.0.1.  The rails command was:

```
$ rails new food_lookup --api
```

When run the Rails server for development work, I am specifying port 3001, but for some reason the server decides it wants to listen on port 3000. `Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000`

```
$ rails server --port=3001
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@food_lookup/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:51: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@food_lookup/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:52: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3001
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@food_lookup/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:138: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.7.0 (ruby 2.4.0-p0), codename: Snowy Sagebrush
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

My logs are empty at this point.

Has anyone seen this?  It was working perfectly fine on my previous Mac with OS X 10.11.  I had the same version of Rails, Ruby, etc, but maybe I forgot to install something on this new machine?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a issue with Puma 3.7.0 which was released this week.

https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1200